# Visual studio code suggest

Tags: visual-studio-code, autosuggest

Does anyone know if VSC can suggest angular properties in HTML. Webstorm does this, but have not been able to find an extension for VSC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once was just released recently: https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service

Comment: If this helped, can you mark it as answered so we know this question is no longer open?

Comment: jep. Stackoverflow didn't allow me. I had to wait 15 minuttes. Thanks again